# How to prevent hazelcast MapStore to load entries before store

Tags: hazelcast

According to [specification](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data) when using write-through mode Hazelcast do the following:

> MapStore can be configured to be write-through by setting the
>   write-delay-seconds property to 0. This means the entries will be put
>   to the data store synchronously.
>
> In this mode, when the map.put(key,value) call returns:
>
> MapStore.store(key,value) is successfully called so the entry is
>   persisted. In-Memory entry is updated. In-Memory backup copies are
>   successfully created on other cluster members (if backup-count is
>   greater than 0).

But in fact it performs MapStore.load(key) before storing each entry. IMap's are configured as following:

```
Config config = ...

MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("data-" + id);
MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = mapConfig.getMapStoreConfig();
mapStoreConfig.setEnabled(true);
mapStoreConfig.setImplementation(new RecordsMapStore());
mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(0);
config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
```

How to prevent such a load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `map.set()` to avoid loading

Comment: + Yes, it works. But it is IMap specific method. Why Map.put has different behaviour?

Comment: @S.Kadakov `map.put` returns previous value for the key. This behavior inherited from Java Map interface

Comment: Ah, yes, sure... Thank you.